# Laravel clean URLs

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, clean-urls

Working on a Laravel project and trying to get a simple URL rewrite working. Here is the .htaccess file, located in the '/public' folder — you can see I have added one rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  # above is default, rule added by me:
  RewriteRule ^articles/page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /articles?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this just 404s. I suspect the default rule is breaking it somehow but don't know enough to fix it.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What URL do you access in browser?

Comment: /articles?page=2 should become /articles/page/2

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to me that your rule to convert `articles/page/{slug}` into `articles?page={slug}` is never hit. Because the rule is the bottom-most and your index.php rewrite rule says it's the "last" rule (`[L]`) and matches anything it wins every time (i.e. there's never any fall-through to your new rule).

Move your articles-specific rule between `RewriteBase` and `RewriteCond` and don't mark it as the last rule (get rid of `[L]`) and try again. That should transform `articles/page/{slug}` into `articles?page=slug` and then pass that on to the index.php rule.

You may also need the `QSA` rewrite rule option to make sure the query string you create works with any query string that exists already.

See:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing order of your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # above is default, rule added by me:
  RewriteRule ^articles/page/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)/?$ /articles?page=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Laravel's routes:

```
Route::get("/articles/page/{article}", "ArticleController@showArticle")
->where("article", "[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+");
```

And the controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller {
    public function showArticle( $articleID ) {}
}
```

I think this is a better approach.